# Getting the actual executable path of current process context - Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to get the actual executable path of a running process through my kernel driver.

I've done the following:

```
static struct kretprobe do_fork_probe = {
    .entry_handler = (kprobe_opcode_t *) process_entry_callback,
    .handler = (kprobe_opcode_t *) NULL,
    .maxactive = 1000,
    .data_size = 0
};

do_fork_probe.kp.addr =     (kprobe_opcode_t*)kallsyms_lookup_name("do_fork");

if ((ret = register_kretprobe(&do_fork_probe)) < 0)
    return -1; 

static int process_entry_callback(struct kretprobe_instance *ri, struct pt_regs *regs)
{

    printk("Executable path = %s\n", executable_path(current));
    return 0;
}
```

The executable_path function:

```
char* executable_path(struct task_struct* process)
{
#define PATH_MAX 4096
char* p = NULL, *pathname;
struct mm_struct* mm = current->mm;
if (mm)
{
    down_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
    if (mm->exe_file) 
    {
        pathname = kmalloc(PATH_MAX, GFP_ATOMIC);
        if (pathname)
            p = d_path(&mm->exe_file->f_path, pathname, PATH_MAX);            
    }
    up_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
} 

return p;
}
```

The problem is that if I run an executable using bash as follows:

```
./execname
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
Executable path = /bin/bash
```

While what I really want is the : execname (Actually its full path but lets start with the name)

Any suggestions?

Comment: you are using printk(), and may not get the complete path pointed by p, because there may be a '\n' after '/bin/bash' within the string, and printk stops when it sees the new line. Just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear what you try to get, so here are list of options:

- `execname` as it is considered by SystemTap. Simple `process->comm` should suffice. That is how `comm` field defined in Kernel:

  ```
  char comm[TASK_COMM_LEN]; /* executable name excluding path
                              - access with [gs]et_task_comm (which lock
                              it with task_lock())
                              - initialized normally by setup_new_exec */
  ```

  But if `bash` is a symlink, than comm should contain symlink's name, not the real executable name.
- `argv[0]` first element of command line arguments array as it seen my application (and may be altered by it). There is a `get_cmdline()` function in kernel, but it seem not to be exported.
- Basename of full path. In this case, do not call `d_path`, just take `d_name` field of dentry:

  ```
  strlcpy(pathname, mm->exe_file->f_path->d_name, PATH_MAX);
  ```

But it sounds like a XY problem. You trying to get executable names for all forking processes? Why not use [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) directly?

```
# stap -v -e 'probe scheduler.process_fork { println(execname()); }'
```

Comment: Why not stap? Because the OP may want to get the exec info and do something with it within the kernel space and stap is userland.

Comment: @icdevppl: actually SystemTap generates kernel modules