# Android avd: how to tell which application calls kernel

Tags: android, c, linux, kernel

I am learning android avd goldfish kernel. I have already inserted a kernel to goldfish kernel. I can hook read contacts API.

How can I tell which application calls Linux kernel?

My kernel source:

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <asm/cacheflush.h>

void **sys_call_table;

asmlinkage int (*original_call_open)(const char *, int, int);
asmlinkage int (*original_call_read)(unsigned int, char *, int);

asmlinkage int our_sys_read(unsigned int fd, char *buf, int count)
{
    if (fd == 0 && count == 1)
        printk("I have files being read: intercept 0x%02X", buf[0]);

    return original_call_read(fd, buf, count);
}

asmlinkage int our_sys_open(const char *file, int flags, int mode)
{
    /* Contacts:
     *   /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db
     * Call records:
     *   /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db
     * SMS records:
     *   /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db
     */
    char *contact ="/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db";
    char *telephony = "/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db";
    char *sms = "/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db";

    if (strcmp(file, contact) == 0)
        printk("The application is reading phone contact records!\n");
    if (strcmp(file, telephony) == 0)
        printk("The application is reading the phone call records!\n");
    if (strcmp(file, sms) == 0)
        printk("The application is reading phone message recording!\n");

    /* printk("A file was opened\n%s\n%d\n%d\n", file, flags, mode); */

    return original_call_open(file, flags, mode);
}

int init_module(void)
{
    sys_call_table = (void*)0xc0022f24;
    original_call_open = sys_call_table[__NR_open];
    original_call_read = sys_call_table[__NR_read];

    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = our_sys_open;
    sys_call_table[__NR_read] = our_sys_read;

    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    /* Restore the original call */
    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = original_call_open;
    sys_call_table[__NR_read] = original_call_read;
}
```

Comment: Try `current->comm`, see here for more options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644637/getting-the-actual-executable-path-of-current-process-context-linux-kernel/28644779#28644779

Comment: Code formatting and translating from Japanese

Comment: what's your meaning of ?@SamProtsenko